# Create SVG from HTML and export it (PHP support)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, svg

I'm searching for tool (jQuery plugin maybe) which would allow me to transform DOM element to .svg and then export it. I checked and googled patiently but didn't find any.

The big picture is that I have multiple charts (generated via Highcharts) in one div and I want to export them as one file. I found answer: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple, but in my div I have also some html data I want to export with those charts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just export a div you can use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to build a file and force the download on the user. I found [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/) and modified it a little for youre case:

```
let saveData = (function () {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        let blob = new Blob([data], {type: "plain/txt"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = document.getElementById("export-content-wrapper").innerHtml,
    fileName = "export.html";

saveData(data, fileName);
```